# Property animations vs View animations for new Android code

Tags: android, android-animation

I am new to Android animations and am reading the introductory articles. The [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html) says that View animation is an **older system** and **easy to use**

As a beginner, should I invest any time understanding how view animations work, or should I focus completely on Property animations ? Is there something property animations are not capable of doing ? Is it "comparatively" very difficult to use property animation for simple stuff like rotate/translate ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As a beginner, should I invest any time understanding how view animations work, or should I focus completely on Property animations ?

I suggest that you focus completely on property animations. At this point, you should be focused on Android 3.0+, where property animations are available. If you need to get your code working on older devices, [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) offers a backport of some of the property animation APIs.

> Is there something property animations are not capable of doing ?

Not that I can think of. Property animations are substantially more powerful, less of a hassle, and more efficient.

> Is it "comparatively" very difficult to use property animation for simple stuff like rotate/translate ?

IMHO, it is substantially easier to use property animations for simple stuff like rotations and translations.

Comment: Since 3.0-3.2 has a 0% market share you may as well say 4.0+ ;)

Comment: @Justin: True, but I did not want to cause confusion, since property animations were added in Android 3.0.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Can you please confirm if ViewPropertyAnimator comes under View or Property animations ? It is added in API level 12, but dev guides say that all property animations are in the package android.animation. Is this an exception ?

Comment: @Raj: `ViewPropertyAnimator` is part of the new animation framework, as is described [in the developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html). View animation is the old API described [elsewhere in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html). And the documentation states that "You can find **most** of the property animation system's APIs in android.animation." (emphasis added)